# How to solve error ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

This select statement in SQL Server returns this error:

> The `ORDER BY` clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, sub queries, and common table expressions, unless `TOP` or `FOR XML` is also specified.

I need the `order by` and I can't remove it

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    stat_flag ,
                    stat_amount ,
                    stat_desc ,
                    trans_name ,
                    serial
          FROM      PostedVoucher
                    JOIN transactions ON trans_code = stat_trans_code
          WHERE     stat_leger = N'clients'
                    AND branch = '1'
                    AND stat_date BETWEEN '2013-12-03 00:00:00.000'
                                  AND     '2013-12-20 00:00:00.000'
          ORDER BY  stat_date
        ) AS t ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(stat_amount) AS sumDebt
          FROM      PostedVoucher
                    JOIN transactions ON trans_code = stat_trans_code
          WHERE     stat_flag = 'd'
                    AND stat_leger = N'clients'
                    AND branch = '1'
                    AND stat_date BETWEEN '2013-12-03 00:00:00.000'
                                  AND     '2013-12-20 00:00:00.000'
        ) AS t1 ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(stat_amount) AS sumcredit
          FROM      PostedVoucher
          WHERE     stat_flag = 'c'
                    AND stat_leger = N'clients'
                    AND branch = '1'
                    AND stat_date BETWEEN '2013-12-03 00:00:00.000'
                                  AND     '2013-12-20 00:00:00.000'
        ) AS t2
```

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostedVoucher](
    [stat_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [branch] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [stat_trans_code] [int] NULL,
    [serial] [int] NULL,
    [stat_leger] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [stat_sub_leger] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [stat_desc] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [stat_amount] [decimal](20, 3) NULL,
    [stat_flag] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ref_dec] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [serial1] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

Insert :----

```
INSERT [dbo].[PostedVoucher] (
    [stat_date], [branch], [stat_trans_code], [serial],
    [stat_leger], [stat_sub_leger], [stat_desc], [stat_amount],
    [stat_flag], [id], [ref_dec], [serial1])   
VALUES (
    CAST(0x0000A28900000000 AS DateTime), N'1', 103, 516,
    N' jkhjkh',  N'uhiuhiu', N' gjhgkjgh', CAST(3.000 AS Decimal(20, 3)),
    N'c', 1, N'system TPL', NULL)
```

Comment: You can either include the ordering column in the result and order outside of the subquery, or use the TOP clause, for example getting the first 5000 results ordered by stat_date.

Comment: Why not doing it in a single query (or two, at worst), using a CASE statement? If you post DDL and some sample data, someone will probably show you how to do it in a single pass. And yes, ORDERing of the results belongs to the outermost SELECT.

Comment: And how's MySQL involved?

Comment: If you are using `top`, then you are not using MySQL.  I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be so simplified by using window functions:

```
Select stat_flag, stat_amount, stat_desc, trans_name, serial,
       sum(case when stat_flag = 'd' then stat_amount else 0 end) over () as sumDebit,
       sum(case when stat_flag = 'c' then stat_amount else 0 end) over () as sumCredit
from PostedVoucher pv join
     transactions t
     on trans_code = stat_trans_code
where stat_leger = N'clients' and
      branch = '1' and
      stat_date between '2013-12-03' and '2013-12-20'
order by stat_date;
```

Subqueries are not needed at all.  Do note that your third subquery probably will not work, because it does not have the join to the `transactions` table.  The other two queries seem to require this table.

I also remove the time component for the dates.  I think the unnecessary time component just clutters the query.

Comment: @feby - if you want *tested* answers, you ought to supply sample data (preferably as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` scripts) and expected results in your question. Otherwise, how do you expect people to know whether their queries actually do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select * from 
 (Select stat_date, stat_flag , stat_amount , stat_desc , trans_name , serial  from    
 PostedVoucher join transactions on trans_code = stat_trans_code where      
 stat_leger = N'clients' and branch='1' and stat_date between '2013-12-03   
00:00:00.000' and '2013-12-20 00:00:00.000' ) as t ,     

 (Select sum(stat_amount) as sumDebt from PostedVoucher join transactions on   

 trans_code = stat_trans_code where stat_flag ='d' and stat_leger = 
   N'clients' and branch='1' and stat_date between '2013-12-03 00:00:00.000'
    and'2013-12-20 00:00:00.000' )as t1 ,
 (Select  sum(stat_amount) as sumcredit from PostedVoucher where stat_flag    
  ='c' and stat_leger=N'clients' and branch='1' and stat_date between '2013-   
 12-03 00:00:00.000' and '2013-12-20 00:00:00.000') as t2 
ORDER BY t.stat_date
```

EDIT:

I recommend you to start using CTE's, your queries will be much more readable. The obove query can be rewritten in the following way:

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT stat_date, stat_flag , stat_amount , stat_desc , trans_name , serial  
    FROM    
        PostedVoucher INNER JOIN  transactions 
            on trans_code = stat_trans_code 
    WHERE       
        stat_leger = N'clients' and branch='1' 
        AND stat_date between '20131203' and '20131220'
),
t1 AS
(
    SELECT sum(stat_amount) as sumDebt 
    FROM 
        PostedVoucher INNER JOIN transactions 
            on trans_code = stat_trans_code 
    WHERE 
        stat_flag ='d' 
        AND stat_leger = N'clients' AND branch='1' 
        AND stat_date between '20131203' AND '20131220'
),
t2 AS
(
    SELECT  SUM (stat_amount) as sumcredit 
    FROM 
        PostedVoucher 
    WHERE
        stat_flag ='c' 
        AND stat_leger=N'clients' 
        AND branch='1' 
        AND stat_date between '20131203' and '20131220'

)
SELECT *
FROM
    t CROSS JOIN t1 CROSS JOIN t2
ORDER BY
    t.t.stat_date
```

Comment: return an error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Change the date literals for example '2013-12-03 00:00:00.000' to '20131203'

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `ORDER BY`, have `TOP 100 PERCENT` in `SELECT`. That effectively returns all the rows, while allowing the `order by`. Something like below:

```
      SELECT    TOP 100 PERCENT stat_flag ,
                stat_amount ,
                stat_desc ,
                trans_name ,
                serial
      FROM      PostedVoucher
                JOIN transactions ON trans_code = stat_trans_code
      WHERE     stat_leger = N'clients'
                AND branch = '1'
                AND stat_date BETWEEN '2013-12-03 00:00:00.000'
                              AND     '2013-12-20 00:00:00.000'
      ORDER BY  stat_date
```